# Undefined index errors from $_POST when accessing through AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I''m trying to use ajax to show result login from php. But it's not work. It's show error Undefined index like this.

> Notice: Undefined index: userEmail in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\controllers\login.controllers.php on line 10
>
> Notice: Undefined index: userPassword in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\controllers\login.controllers.php on line 10
>
> Login failed

Here are my source code:
login.views.php

```
<form id="loginForm" action="/controllers/login.controllers.php" method="post">
    <input id ="userEmail" type="text" name="userEmail" placeholder="Email">
    <input id ="userPassword" type="password" name="userPassword" placeholder="Password">
    <button id ="loginSubmit" type="submit" name="loginSubmit">Login</button>
    <div id="msg"></div>
</form>
```

login.Controller.php

```
<?php

    include("../models/user.models.php");
    include("../models/dataBase.models.php");
    $dbc = new dataBase();
    $connect = $dbc->connect('localhost','root','','how_database','','hide');

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
        $user = new user();
        if ($user->login($connect,$_POST['userEmail'],$_POST['userPassword']) == true){
            echo "Login Successful";
        }
        else {
            echo "Login failed";
        }
    }

    $dbc->close($connect);
?>
```

loginAjax.js

```
$("#loginSubmit").click(function(){
   if ($("#userEmail").val() == "" || $("userPassword").val() == "") {
       $("div#msg").html("Please enter your email and password");
   }
   else {
       $.post(
           $("#loginForm").attr("action"),
           $("#loginForm:input").serializeArray(),
           function(data){
               $("div#msg").html(data);
           }
       );
   }

   $("#loginForm").submit(function(){
       return false;
   })
});
```

**Update Question:**
Now i want to add message "Waiting" when after click submit button, hide it when show result messages. What must i do?. Thanks.

Comment: Try `$("#loginForm").serialize()` instead of `$("#loginForm:input").serializeArray()`

Comment: Thank you. It's worked. :). But can you expain to me the different between them?

Comment: I added an answer for you.

Comment: Now i want to add message "Waiting" when after click submit button, hide it when show result messages. What must i do?. Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should need to call `serialize()` on the `form`, not `serializeArray()` on the list of inputs. Try this:

```
$.post(
    $("#loginForm").attr("action"),
    $("#loginForm").serialize(),
    function(data){
        $("div#msg").html(data);
    }
);
```

The difference between the functions is the format the output. `serializeArray()` returns an object, which may not be in the correct format for your receiving endpoint, and `serialize()` turns the values of the form in to a querystring.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$("#loginSubmit").click(function(){
   if ($("#userEmail").val() == "" || $("userPassword").val() == ""){
       $("div#msg").html("Please enter your email and password");
   }else{
       var formData = new FormData($("#loginSubmit")[0]);
       $.ajax({
          url: $("#loginForm").attr("action"),
          type: 'POST',
          data: formData,
          async: false,
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (data) {
            //here success
          },
         cache: false,
         contentType: false,
         processData: false
         });
   }

   $("#loginForm").submit(function(){
       return false;
   })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$("#loginForm").serialize()
```

instead of

```
 $("#loginForm:input").serializeArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
 $.post(
       $("#loginForm").attr("action"),
       $("#loginForm:input").serialize(),
       function(data){
           $("div#msg").html(data);
       }
```